# How to detect which pod makes network request in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, calico

External firewall logs show blocked connection from < node IP >:< big port >. 
The current cluster uses calico networking.

How do I detect which pod trying to connect?

Answer (score 1):

This would usually be pretty hard to work out, you would have to check the NAT table on the node where the packets exited to the public internet.